# How to download from Apple's QuickLook link scheme "x-apple-ql-magic"?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, quicklook

***TL;DR** - I want to download a .csv and other files from a link, and present a UIActivityViewController.*

I'm working in an app with lots of WKWebViews. In one of the delegate methods, `decidePolicyForNavigationAction:`, the available URL is a URL compatible with URLRequests, and I can download just fine from it. (`navigationAction.request.url`)

In *another* delegate method `decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:` the response's url (`navigationResponse.response.url`) identifies as part of Apple's QuickLook framework scheme, and contains this: `x-apple-ql-magic`. I was trying to use a `QLPreviewController`, but couldn't populate the dataSource with a remote file I wanted to download.

My goal is: When a link points to a downloadable file, like a .csv or PDF, give a user the option to share this file via `UIActivityViewController`.

**How can I download remote files from this scheme: `x-apple-ql-magic`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t. When WKWebView previews a file such as CSV, it is internally converted to HTML by Quick Look to be rendered by WebKit. The x-apple URL is the URL of the converted content. It should not be exposed to you, you should be seeing the original URL instead, please file a bug.

Why do you want to use the response delegate in the first place instead of the delegate at link tap time?

Comment: Because the x-apple url has a .csv extension, which is easier to check, and there are some QuickLook methods like `canPreview` that I was trying to use in the `navigationResponse` delegate method. Great answer, though, thank you!

Comment: Is there any way to know the actual MimeType instead of `text/html` for csv file?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the question, but in any case you should not rely on these x-apple URLs. These are implementation details and can change. They are not API.